# How to add customised boxplot to histogram in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, boxplot

I have created a histogram and have removed the outliers that are higher and lower the limits given by `boxplot.stat` function. Then using `cowplot`, I have added a boxplot using `geom_boxplot` on top of the histogram. However, `geom_boxplot` and `boxplot.stat` give different values for all statistics hence the my boxplot shows outliers which have been removed in the histogram below. I tried to manually change the values of the boxplot by inserting the values from `boxplot.stats`.

**Here is a reproducible example:**

```
set.seed(1)
Data <- data.table(
  "X" = sample(1:100),
  "Y" = sample(1:100))
)

numeric <-colnames(Data)

for (c in numeric){

  #Remove Outliers:
  stats <- boxplot.stats(Data[,get(c)])$stats
  upper.lim <- stats[5]
  median <- stats[3]
  lower.lim <- stats[1]


df2<-Data[!(get(c)>upper.lim | get(c)<lower.lim),] #filter to remove outliers

plotmain <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=df2[,get(c)])) +
  geom_histogram(colour="#102c59", fill="#5182d1", alpha=0.7) + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = comma,breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
  ylab("Number of records") + 
  xlab(gsub("_", " ", c)) +
  ggtitle(title) + 
  theme_grey(base_size=8) 

xbox <- axis_canvas(plotmain, axis = "x", coord_flip = TRUE) + 
  geom_boxplot(data=df2,aes_string(x=c, ymin="lower.lim", lower=stats[2], middle="median", upper=stats[4], ymax="upper.lim"),stat="identity",
               outlier.shape=NA) + coord_flip() #add boxplot on top of histogram

p1 <- insert_xaxis_grob(plotmain, xbox, grid::unit(0.3, "in"), position = "top")
histbox <- ggdraw(p1) #join the two plots

g<-grid.arrange(histbox, tbl, layout_matrix=rbind(c(1),c(1),c(1),c(1),c(2)), nrow=4)
histbox <- ggdraw(p1)

ggsave(file="g.png",width=20, height=15, units="cm")
```

}

**The error I get is:**

```
Error: geom_boxplot requires the following missing aesthetics: x
```

I have tried inserting x=1 and x="" in the aesthetic but that gives me an entirely filled black box.

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94mTD.png): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94mTD.png)

Comment: Could you maybe share some data with us, for example posting the output of `dput(head(df))`, so that we can try to reproduce your graphic?
You could also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1)